# How can I use --changedSince and --onlyChanged in jest?

Tags: git, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I want to use [changedSince](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#changedsince) and [onlyChanged](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#onlychanged) flag for jest. I changed lots of tests and also files that the tests depends on. And according to the documentation of jest cli flags:

> **changedSince**: Runs tests related the changes since the provided branch. If the current branch has diverged from the given branch, then only changes made locally will be tested.
>
> **onlyChanged**: Alias -o. Attempts to identify which tests to run based on which files have changed in the current repository. Only works if you're running tests in a git/hg repository at the moment and requires a static dependency graph (ie. no dynamic requires).

But when I run `jest --changedSince=master` or `jest --onlyChanged` it runs 0 tests without giving anything in the terminal at all.

`jest --listTests` lists all the tests. However when I run `jest --listTests --changedSince=master` or `jest --listTests --onlyChanged`, it lists no test.

Answer (score 11):

I found `--changedSince` and `--onlyChanged` to be a little funky too. However, what you can do is use [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) and Jest's `--findRelatedTests` and add it to a pre-commit hook.

> **--findRelatedTests {spaceSeparatedListOfSourceFiles}:** Find and run the tests that cover a space separated list of source files that were passed in as arguments. Useful for pre-commit hook integration to run the minimal amount of tests necessary. Can be used together with --coverage to include a test coverage for the source files, no duplicate --collectCoverageFrom arguments needed.

Here is the change you need to make in your `package.json` file.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "CI=true jest",
    "test:staged": "CI=true jest --env=jsdom --findRelatedTests"
  }
}
```

And,

```
"lint-staged": {
  "src/**/*.js": [
    "test:staged",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

This way, on every commit, Jest will run tests for related source files only. Don't forget to set the `CI=true` environment variable or your tests will run in watch mode and never end.

If you still want to run the full suite of tests `npm test` will do the trick. Also, it's better to have a CI environment to run all your tests when you push to a branch or send a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

you can use '-o' flag to run changed test file in the watch mode.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli

```
jest -o
```