# JEST: Is there a solution to run tests only for changed/impacted files?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

There are few solutions given by Jest in that direction. I have tried out most of the solutions like `--findRelatedTests`, `--onlyChanged`, `--changedSince`. But there are few shortcomings in every solutions. I thought `--changedSince` is the best match for me.

```
jest --changedSince=origin/master --coverage
```

It mostly covers the basic scenarios like running test files corresponding to the changed source files. But it does not handle few scenarios like if a source-file(say `a.js`) is **deleted** and same(`a.js`) is being used(imported) in another file(say `b.js`), it does not run *tests* for any of the files(`a.js` or `b.js`). It does not seem to run tests for parent files where it was imported.

Is there a clean solution which can handle all the scenarios like file rename/deletion, dynamic imports, running tests for the parent modules where it was imported or any other impact that may happen when you change a source file?

Answer (score 14):

**Quick answer**: No.

**Long answer**: Yes, but it's not that clean or straight forward.

I have achieved this through three steps.

**STEP 1:**

You can achieve this by a bit of scripting. First you'll want to get a list of all **the changed files through Git**.

This can be achieved through a function like the below:

```
const util = require("util")
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec)

const detectChangedFiles = async () => {
    try {
        const { stdout, stderr } = await exec("git diff origin/master --name-only")

        if (stderr) {
            throw new Error(stderr)
        }

        return stdout.replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/client\//g, " ")

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

**STEP 2:**

Secondly, you'd wanna **get a list of related tests for those files** like the below:

```
 const findRelatedTests = async () => {
    const changedFiles = await detectChangedFiles()

    try {
        const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`jest --listTests --findRelatedTests ${changedFiles}`)

        if (stderr) {
            throw new Error(stderr)
        }

        if (!stdout) {
            console.log('No tests found for the changed files :)')
        } else {
            return stdout.replace(/\n/g, " ")
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

**STEP 3:**

And finally you'd wanna feed all of those tests to jest to run;

```
const runRelatedTests = async () => {
    const relatedTests = await findRelatedTests()

    if (relatedTests) {
        try {
            const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`jest --ci --coverage ${relatedTests}`)

            if (stderr) {
                throw new Error(stderr)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

One of the **limitations** of this implementation is that I"m always diffing against the **master** and that's not a good assumption. In special cases, one may chose to merge against another branch.

This can be handled in a few ways;

1. If you're running a cli, pass the arguments to the cli and consume it in your script
2. If you're running in pipeline like Gitlab and assuming that this is a MR/PR, consider using some available environment varibale ( in this case **CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME** )

Comment: @pauya-ataei I think your script does the same thing as `--changedSince` option. In the step-2, if a file is deleted or renamed, It is not able to detect the related test files.

Comment: @DebajitMajumder it still should be able to detect those tests... because we are feeding the result of the git diff, and git diff includes those deleted files.

Comment: I had the same expectation. But atleast in my case it's not working probably because `--findRelatedTests` can not find any reference of the deleted source files. Do you have any working example for this deletion scenario?

Comment: I can think of something, but why would you wanna run tests for deleted files ?

Comment: If a source file gets deleted, but if we miss to delete corresponding UT file or if we miss to delete the reference/import of deleted source file from other files in that case I would like my test suite to break. 

I know that my build will only break if there if there is any reference of the deleted file in any other source files but it will not take care if there is any import left in test files.

Comment: Using `jest` in combination with `lint-staged` giving desired behaviour: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51827563/4591347

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to diff from the current branch? For example, if I'm working on the "feature1" branch, then diff with "origin/feature1".

Comment: @DouglasNassifRomaJunior yea, just change the branch name in git diff